# Can a Visual Studio Macro "$(TargetDir)" be used at design time?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-macros

Is it possible to resolve the path of $(TargetDir) in code at design time? This would be useful for me because I have two different XML files that need processing, one for Debug, and one for Release.

I though about instantiating an instance of ITextTemplatingEngineHost since it has a ResolvePath() method, but there is no documentation on how to do this.

Comment: Macros have a value at build time, not design time.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks. If you can make that an answer, I can accept it.